# ssh connectiton timed out - route issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup an ec2 instance and I am receiving a connection time out.

I have downloaded the pem file to ~/.ssh folder.

I have done `chmod 400 file.pem`

I am trying :

`ssh -v -i AWS.pem ubuntu@ec2-54...1.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-5.....compute-1.amazonaws.com [54....1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 54....1 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-5...1.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

The instance is up and running.

I am not sure for the route options though.

In the route table it shows:

```
Destination: 172.....0/16

Target: local

Status: Active

Propagated : No
```

I can't try to add another route because next to the add button  it says:

There are not any Internet Gateway, Network Interface, or Virtual Private Gateway targets.

But the network interfcase status is :  in-use

The public IP is ok ( the same that I am trying to connect through ssh ).

I am not sure what else I need to check.

---

From Security group:

```
Inbound:

Type: SSH
Protocol: TCP
Port Range:22
Source:0.0.0.0/0

Outbound:

Type: All traffic1
Protocol: All
Port Range:All
Destination:0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Check Security Group, port 22 must be allowed

Comment: @DusanBajic:Hi, I updated.It is allowed

Comment: The simplest correct setup: your instance has public IP, it is in subnet which has route 0.0.0.0/0 to internet gateway (which is in same vpc where the subnet is). This is all already there if you placed the instance in default vpc/subnet. If you created the new vpc/subnet, you need to create internet gateway and add route to subnet's routing table.

Comment: @DusanBajic:Yes,it the default

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the case that your system is on the AWS network but isn't routed to the internet yet. i.e. your system can see other systems internally but nobody can see it from the outside, this is despite the firewall being set.

IF this is the case; you need to ensure that your VPC and Internet Gateways are all setup on AWS to do this on AWS:

(Note: If you already have a VPC and a Subnet, then skip to item-5):

1) From Services -> select VPC -> Click on the (xxx VPCs) link

2) Click "Create VPC" if you don't have one already give it a name-tag, and a subnet mask (something like 192.168.1.0/24)

3) Select "Subnets" on the left menu, and then "Create Subnet" if you don't have one already

4) Enter a name tag, and then select the VPC you created already.

5) Select "Internet Gateways" from the left menu, Click on "Create Internet Gateway"

6) Enter a name-tag, and OK

7) Click on your new Internet Gateway, and then right-click, select "Attach VPC", this should link the GW into the VPC to allow the route.

8) Take a note of your Gateway (i.e. igw-123456)

9) Go back into "Subnets", select your subnet in question

10) Click on "Route Table", Click "Edit"

11) Click "Add Route" from the bottom,

12) Enter your Default Route to route everything, in this case it should be "0.0.0.0/0"

13) Enter the copied Gateway address (i.e. igw-123456) in the second box.

14) OK

This should allow your server to connect to the internet and also for you to see it if your firewall allows you to.

I hope this helps

Kind Regards
Heider

Comment: #9 - Should be: " Go to 'Route Tables' on left " if you click "Subnets" on left you can only edit associations.

Answer (score 0):

Finally..At the Inbound options,at the source, I had to put my IP and not 0.0.0.0/.

Comment: Allowing 0.0.0.0/0 inbound will allow all addresses, including yours.

Comment: @RodrigoM:Who knows then?I just selected my IP and it worked immediately!

Comment: Good to know.  SSH should be restricted to your IP anyway for security